# how to disable duplicate open of same childform in a tab control

Tags: c#, winforms

what i want to happen is when i open the specific form in a tab control it will show and when i accidentally click the button of that specic form is it will automatically focused on that form and to avoid open it again in another tab page.

Here is my method:

```
private void CreateTabPage(Form form)
{ 
form.TopLevel=false;
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
tabPage.Text = form.Text;
tabPage.Controls.Add(form);
form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

currenttab = form;
tabPage.Tag = form;
tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
form.Show();

}`
```

and here is my code in a button eventhandler code:

`CreateTabPage(new Form1());`

Comment: I think you might be saying that each time you click the button it opens a new form, and that you want is for the existing form to be given the focus when the button is clicked, but I'm not sure whether that really is what you mean. Please consider rephrasing your question to make it clear what the current behaviour is and what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: What i mean based on my code is when i open the Form1 as a childform in the Tab Control it will be open in Tab Control as a new tab page and whenever i triggered the same button again to show the Form1 it will automatically focused on Form1 tab which is already open and avoid to open Form1 as a new tab page in Tab Control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `new Form1()`, which creates a new instance of the form each time it's called. Instead, you need to hold a reference to the existing instance of `Form1`, and show that instance, for example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var form2 = new Form2(this);
            form2.Show();
        }
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private readonly Form1 form1;

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.form1 = form1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.form1.Activate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the existing TabPages and see if one of them already has the same type of the form being requested:

```
private void CreateTabPage(Form form)
{
    foreach(TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        if(tp.Controls.Count>0 && tp.Controls[0].GetType().Equals(form.GetType())) {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
            return;
        }
    }

    form.TopLevel = false;
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
    tabPage.Text = form.Text;
    tabPage.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    currenttab = form;
    tabPage.Tag = form;
    tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
    form.Show();
}
```